# How to get C++ program to stop evaluating operational statements?

Tags: c++

I am taking a beginner C++ course and my first project is to assess if the date inputed is a valid date or not and if the date is in a leap year. I am almost done with the project my only issue is that everytime an invalid date is inputed the program treats it as a valid and an invalid date at the same time. For example, when you put a valid date in such as, 11/12/2004 the output is "The date November 12, 2004 is in a leap year.".Then when you put an invalid date in such as, 40/12/2004, the output is "The month must be in the interval [1,12]. is in a leap year".

How do I stop the program from telling if the year is in a leap/common year if the input is invalid?

```
int month, day, year;
cout<<"Enter numeric values for the current date [mm dd yyyy] ->";
cin>>month>>day>>year;

if (month > 12 || month < 1){
    cout<<"The month must be in the interval [1,12]. ";
}
else if (day > 31 || day < 1){
    cout<<"The day must be in interval [1,31]. ";
}
else if (year < 1582){
    cout<<"The year must come after 1582. ";
}
else if (month == 2 && day > 29){
    cout<<"The day in February cannot be greater than 29. ";
}
else if (month == 2 && day == 29 && year%400 == 400){
    cout<<"February cannot have 29 days in a common year. ";
}
else if (month == 4 && day == 31){
    cout<<"The day in April cannot be 31. ";
}
else if (month == 6 && day == 31){
    cout<<"The day in June cannot be 31. ";
}
else if (month == 9 && day == 31){
    cout<<"The day in September cannot be 31. ";
}
else
    if (month == 11 && day == 31){
    cout<<"The day in November cannot be 31. ";
}


if (month==1){
    cout<<"The date January "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==2){
    cout<<"The date February "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==3){
    cout<<"The date March "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==4){
    cout<<"The date April "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==5){
    cout<<"The date May "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==6){
    cout<<"The date June "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==7){
    cout<<"The date July "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month ==8){
    cout<<"The date August "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month == 9){
    cout<<"The date September "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month==10){
    cout<<"The date October "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month == 11){
    cout<<"The date November "<<day<<", "<<year;
}
else if (month == 12) {
    cout<<"The date December "<<day<<", "<<year;
}

if (year%400==0) {}
else if (year%4 == 0 && year%100 !=0){
    cout<<" is in a leap year.";
}
else cout<<" is in a common year."<< endl;

return 0;}
```

Comment: Add `return` statements to your `if` blocks that validate the input

Comment: You can `return 1;` at that point for example. (the 1 as opposed to 0 is just to indicate an error, it's convention)

Comment: Unrelated: For leap years, you probably want to put the `year % 400 == 0` condition in with the other two: `if( year%4 == 0 && (year % 100 !=0 || year % 400 == 0) ) { /* leap year */ }`

Answer (score 0):

An easy method is to have your function return `false` when you determine the input is invalid:

```
bool Is_Date_Valid(unsigned int month,
                   unsigned int day,
                   unsigned int year)
{
    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12)) return false;
    if ((day < 1) || (day > 31)) return false;
    if (month < 1582) return false;
    //...
    // If everything is valid.
    return true;
}
```

If you haven't covered functions yet, you could place it into the `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    int month, day, year;
    std::cout << "Enter date (mm dd yy): ";
    std::cin >> month >> day >> year;

    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid month.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ((day < 1) || (day > 31))
    {
         std::cout << "Invalid day\n";
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //...
    std::cout << "Date is valid.\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```